# How to pass a parameter from view to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I have an app in ruby on rails with a view which has some parameters displaying on screen.

```
 <%= link_to l(:label_statistics),
            {:action => 'stats', :id => @project, :repository_id => @repository.identifier_param},
            :class => 'icon icon-stats' if @repository.supports_all_revisions? %>
```

I'd like to catch the variable `@repository.name` and use it in the function I have in my controller.

How do I to do it?

Comment: You're already being passed the ID for the repository. Why not just look it up in your controller?

Comment: because the controller is other which doesn't have any information about the repository. When I try to get direct access, I receive nil.

Answer (score 0):

In your stats action, assuming you have a Repository model and the record containing name exists in your database.

```
@repository = Repository.find(params[:repository_id])
@repository.name
```

If not, you could pass it along with everything else,

```
<%= link_to l(:label_statistics),
    {:action => 'stats', 
    :id => @project,
    :repository_id => @repository.identifier_param,
    :repository_name => @repository.name},
    :class => 'icon icon-stats' if @repository.supports_all_revisions? %>
```

Then in the controller, access it via `params[:repository_name]`

Comment: if I create a new symbol in my link_to_l (example :asdsad => @repository.name), do you know if this will work when I execute the command params[:asdsad] ?

Comment: Any parameters that Rails doesn't recognize will get passed as a querystring. So you'll get `yourpath/?asdsad=repositoryname`. You can access that via params[:asdsad], yes.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it through the parameters. [Doc for li_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

```
link_to can also produce links with anchors or query strings:

link_to "Comment wall", profile_path(@profile, :anchor => "wall") # => <a href="/profiles/1#wall">Comment wall</a>

link_to "Ruby on Rails search", :controller => "searches", :query => "ruby on rails" # => <a href="/searches?query=ruby+on+rails">Ruby on Rails search</a>

link_to "Nonsense search", searches_path(:foo => "bar", :baz => "quux") # => <a href="/searches?foo=bar&amp;baz=quux">Nonsense search</a>
```